# When "especially" is at the end of a list, does it apply to the whole list or only the last item

Tags: word-usage

English is my second language, so be gentle if this seems silly ...

This sentence puzzles me:

> China's prolonged silence about its destruction of the Feng Yun 1-C satellite, which it launched in 1999, has been almost as unnerving to its potential enemies (*America, Japan and Taiwan **especially***) as the experiment itself.

In the parentheses does *especially* apply to only Taiwan or all three countries?

And how about in this sentence?

> China's aim is to signal to America and its protégés in Asia—Taiwan
>   and Japan *especially*...

Comment: It's inherently ambiguous as written. You could pause after *Taiwan* (put a comma there, in writing) to unambiguously indicate only *Japan* was especially being signalled. Or you could move *especially* to before *Taiwan* to unambiguously indicate *both* were especially being signalled.

Comment: For some reason, the first seems far more ambiguous to me than the second. I can’t pause or intonate the latter sentence in a way to make it sound like ‘especially’ refers only to Japan, but I can with the first. To single out Japan in the second phrase, I would unwaveringly say either “Taiwan and especially Japan” or “Taiwan and, in particular, Japan”. Is that just me?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: That's worth posting as an answer, not just a comment.

Answer (score 1):

It is a little bit ambiguous, but it seems to apply to the whole list, especially as the list is already a subset of a broader category (e.g., America's "proteges in Asia").

If the list read, for example, "America, Japan, and, especially, Taiwan," the 'especially' would apply only to Taiwan.

Comment: Your first sentence depends on making the assumption that America has *other* "proteges in Asia" besides Taiwan and Japan - which is obviously a matter of opinion, and might be even more so with an alternative but syntactically identical sentence. The second sentence is true enough, but a pause in speech (or a comma in writing, assuming it's not interpreted as an [Oxford comma](http://oxforddictionaries.com/words/what-is-the-oxford-comma)) has the same effect without needing to move the word *especially*.

Answer (score 1):

It's inherently ambiguous as written. In example #2 you could pause after *Taiwan* (put a comma there, in writing) to unambiguously indicate only *Japan* was especially being signalled (but that in the written form that wouldn't work if the reader interpreted it as an [Oxford comma](http://oxforddictionaries.com/words/what-is-the-oxford-comma)).

In short, it's trivial to disambiguate this one in *speech*, but not 100% certain in the written form.

Of course, you could move *especially* to an earlier position in the list to unambiguously indicate that *all countries following that word* were especially being signalled.